# How to configure Phalcon with Lighttpd

Tags: php, phalcon, lighttpd

I am trying to use `Phalcon` with `Lighttpd`. After downloading and placing phalcon C extension in `php/ext` folder I added the line `extension=php_phalcon.dll` to php.ini file and getting the following error.

```
PHP version : php-5.5.23-nts-Win32-VC11-x86
Phalcon Extension : phalcon_x86_VC11_php5.5.0_2.0.0_nts

Contents of php.ini: http://pastebin.com/vimmjUm1
Output of phpinfo(): http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/93943/73d3d8d5fd772bc0dd9acef37c3a92e5
```

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'C:\php\php_phalcon.dll' - The specified module could not be found. 
>   in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 1):

After checking out the screenshots, it looks like you have the extension in the wrong path.

As you can see from the output of `phpinfo()`, the extensionpath is `C:\php` and that is where the `.dll` file should be.

From what you say it sounds like you put the extension DLL's inside `C:\php\ext` which is incorrect.

I recommend to always check the PHP info for parsed and active config.

Comment: I made a typo in question. `extension=php_phalcon.dll` is in my ini file

Comment: Are you sure that the php_phalcon.dll file is there? It sounds like you've just copied the sourcecode without the binaries.

Comment: But is the ``php_phalcon.dll`` file there?

Comment: yes its there  `php_phalcon.dll` in `php\ext` folder

Comment: And you're sure that this is the right extension folder? What is the configures extension folder in your php.ini? Can you pasebin the output from ``phpinfo()`` ?

Comment: Can you post the output of the ``phpinfo()`` function, instead of your ``php.ini``?

Comment: Here is my php.ini file http://pastebin.com/vimmjUm1 and here is my php info screen shot http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/93943/73d3d8d5fd772bc0dd9acef37c3a92e5

Comment: As you can see, you should have the extension in the following folder: ``C:\php`` - you can tell from the "ext_dir" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

there are some things that must compatible with each other:

```
1- Version of PHP and phalcon 
2- PHP 32bit can load phalcon 32bit
3- In windows download and install all version of VC 9,10,11,...
```

I have the same problem but with WAMP. My problem is about version of VC and phalcon dll.